# how can I make it so my unity trees load in their leaves from farther away?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem. I made some terrain in unity and painted my unity trees on it. but when my camera is to far away the trees appear to have no leaves on them! Its annoying because I can only see leaves on the trees like 10-20 feet in front of me. please help!

Answer (score 0):

In the terrain settings there should be "Tree & detail objects" where you can increase detail distance and fade length.

Comment: THANK YOU  this sounds like exactly what I need